# Order of elements in soapUI request

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, soapui

I have a wcf application  with 2 operation contracts with [XmlSerializerFormat]  and remaining in the default [DataContractFormat].

In both cases I am using data contracts for requests and response and specify order of properties like

```
       [DataMember(Order = 10)]   
   public string Tel
   {
       get;                  // in [DataContractFormat] method
       set;
   }
```

and

```
         [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Order = 11)]
    public string Taxi
    {
        get;                      // in  [XmlSerializerFormat] method
        set;
    }
```

I use SoapUI for testing. When I change the order of elements in request:

1) [DataContractFormat] methods work as expected.
2) [XmlSerializerFormat] methods produce non standard results.
    I have read a few  articles related to this issue( 1.[blog](https://snook.ca/archives/other/soap_request_pa) 2.[so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667771/wcf-and-input-parameter-order-in-soap-envelope) 3.[another blog](http://neimke.blogspot.in/2012/03/serialization-ordering-causes-problems.html))

but could not understand properly. How do I get both types to work similarly?

Thank you

Comment: It seems changing order of elements in [DataContractFormat] method requests **doesn't work in all cases** like I've said in the question. However [XmlSerializerFormat] methods remain adamant in rejecting any order changes

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668479/7435291)
 is the way to go about it. i.e to use the order in the default schema of api request